# ActionView setOnClickListener not called

Tags: android, tooltip

I have a menu item. For which I want to show tooltip. So I set ImageButton as ActionView but setOnClickListener is not getting called.

```
val menuItem = menu?.getItem(0)

        info { "Menu item not null" }
        val addView = menuItem?.actionView as ImageButton

        // just adding some padding to look better
        val density = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density
        val padding = (5 * density).toInt()
        addView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding)

        addView.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_add_white_24dp, null))

        val toolTip = ToolTip().setDescription(activity.getString(R.string.coach_add_dependant)).setGravity(Gravity.LEFT or Gravity.BOTTOM)
        info { "Menu item not null1" }
        val addDepMenu = TourGuide.init(activity)
                .with(TourGuide.Technique.Click)
                .motionType(TourGuide.MotionType.ClickOnly)
                .setPointer(Pointer())
                .setToolTip(toolTip)
                .setOverlay(Overlay())
                .playOn(addView)
        info { "Menu item not null2" }

        addView.setOnClickListener {
            info { "Menu item not null3" }
            info { "Add view clicked" }
            addDepMenu.cleanUp()

        }
```

Menu file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/addUserMenu"
        android:title="Add User"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"/>
</menu>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you checked if "onOptionsItemSelected()" is called for that menu item (addUserMenu)?